# windows automated task

Tags: c#

i have c# program to save the path of the files and the password.

How can my program talk with backend program (ie 3rd application program) transparent to the user, to perform the tasks. And based on the data i captured using my c# progeam, given to use with  that 3rd app program.

My C# program is just a frontend interface to automated the repeative task for keep manual operation from one source folder to destination folder to save operator time.

The problem is, i don't understand how to do this. I only know we need something like window automate task to get that done. How can i integrate my program + 3rd app.+window automate task, together?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create your program as a Windows Service, and make it run constantly
2. As for the data passing goes, you can output an XML file ( or write to a database), and let the 3 party app to use.

You may want to write a clearer question next time.